# How can I make ChatGPT output a number list that can be copied and pasted?

Tags: list, chatgpt

I can make ChatGPT output a numbered list, but the numbers disappear when it is copied and pasted.

[image: ChatGPT output]

The above is the output and if I copy and paste it in the notepad, it becomes as below.

[image]

How can I keep the numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer.

I should click the copy button instead of pressing Ctrl + C.
The copy button is just on the left of the thumbs-up button. (circled in red below)

[image: copy button]

Then the result is as below.

[image: numbered list]